# How map() function works in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to apply numpy function average on pandas dataframe object. Since, I want to apply this function on row wise element of dataframe object, therefore I have applied map function. code is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3),columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
df_averge_row = df.apply(np.average(weights=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]]),axis=0)
```

Unfortunately, it is not working. Any Suggestion would be helpful

Comment: This is a weighted average, right? can't you do df.mean (axis = 1)?

Comment: @ansev  I want weighted average. np.mean will give only average

Comment: Will the weights be 1,2,3,4,5 or is it just an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have 3 columns in each row and are applying the function row-wise (not column wise) per your question, the weights function can only have 3 elements (one per each column in a given row, let's say [1,2,3]):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3),columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3'])
weights = weights=[1,2,3]
df_averge_row = df.apply(lambda x: np.average(x, weights=weights),axis=1)

df_averge_row
```

out:

```
0    0.618617
1    0.757778
2    0.551463
3    0.497654
4    0.755083
dtype: float64
```